# Triangles with a perimeter of n

Tags: c#

I wanna print how many triangles exist having the perimeter of n.(with integer sides).
Actually the formula I used is here.
*T(n): n=even --> n^2/48   |  n=odd --> (n+3)^2/48.*
and here is my code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double m = 0;

            if(n%2==0)
            {
                m =Math.Round( n * n / 48.0);
            }
            else
            {
                m = Math.Round((n + 3) * (n + 3) / 48.0);
            }

            Console.Write(m);
        }
```

It actually gives me half of the score.

Comment: What do you mean with half the score? What are the expected input and output?

Comment: From an example at [A005044 Alcuin's sequence](http://oeis.org/A005044), "There are 4 triangles of perimeter 11, with sides 1,5,5; 2,4,5; 3,3,5; 3,4,4. So a(11) = 4." Does your result agree with that? Note that 2,4,5 is taken to be the same triangle as 4,2,5.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832945/integer-triangles-with-perimeter-n

Comment: [A005044](https://oeis.org/A005044) mentioned by @AndrewMorton confirms the formula given by the asker. Namely, its first comment is `a(n) is the number of triangles with integer sides and perimeter n`, and it has a formula `a(n) = round(n^2/48) if n is even; a(n) = round((n+3)^2/48) if n is odd. - James East, May 01 2016`.

Comment: @Martheen I mean if there are6 tests, I get 3 out of 6.
and to AndrewMorton yes my answer is the same

Comment: The code given looks correct. What are the 6 tests?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen thats 1

Comment: It was mentioned in a comment to a currently deleted answer that you can avoid the use of `double` by saying `int m;` before the `if` and then using `m = (n * n + 24) / 48` in the even case, and `m = ((n + 3) * (n + 3) + 24) / 48` in the odd case. This works by integer division. However, your method with floating-point division and `Round` looks correct as well.

Comment: Ok i will try it

Comment: As @Martheen asked, what is the input, and what output do you get, and what output did you expect? It is entirely unclear what your question is, and I cannot see a problem with your original code. What was "3 out of 6" you mentioned? (It is true that if the input `n` is `6` (so perimeter 6), then only one triangle exists, namely the equilateral triangle of side length 2, so the output `m` should be `1` or `1.0` in that case.)

Comment: Actually  there is a problem in a site that have testcases with unknown inputs, so i cant(don't know) say which inputs my code mistakes for.

Comment: Certainly, the result should be the same. Both give the correct answer. I suppose this not about _negative_ input values? You should not accept negative numbers as inputs.

Comment: yes the input is surely larger than 3

Comment: Is it a public test on that site? Can you link it? It seems impossible to help you without seeing the test cases that fail. It is certain that the input is an integer? Are you supposed to handle extremely large integers, inputs over 2'147'483'647?

Comment: Brooooo it's solved now. It was mentioned in the question, that n<=1 000 000 which i clearly didn't pay attention to, so I replace int with long and it worked :)) Thanks for your all help and time you spend 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was the asker was supposed to handle values `n` up to 1_000_000. But for such inputs `n * n` which is done as integer multiplication, overflows silently and produces an unexpected result.

(Curiously, for these cases it could have worked to switch to `double` earlier, like saying `n * (n / 48.0)` or `(double)n * n / 48.0` instead of `n * n / 48.0`.)

You can use a syntax like `checked { /* statements here */}` or (inside an expression) `checked(n * n)` to get an exception rather than a silent loss of significant bits that the fixed-width integer type cannot hold.

The asker fixed it by switching to `long`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long n = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double m;

    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        m = Math.Round(n * n / 48.0);
    }
    else
    {
        m = Math.Round((n + 3) * (n + 3) / 48.0);
    }

    Console.Write(m);
}
```

If you have access to System.Numerics, you can write a solution that works for even bigger inputs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BigInteger n = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    BigInteger m;

    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        m = (n * n + 24) / 48;
    }
    else
    {
        m = ((n + 3) * (n + 3) + 24) / 48;
    }

    Console.Write(m);
}
```

where we use integer division `/`, and the trick of adding half the denominator to the numerator ensures correct rounding to nearest.